# Web garden environment and caching in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, caching, appfabric-cache, web-garden

We are planning to move our web application to web garden environment.
We are leaning towards Windows Server App Fabric Caching to provide distributed caching.
Is it the right approach?/
Is there anyother way to achieve distributed caching apart from Appfabric Caching?

Answer (score 0):

The web garden is many pools on the same computer. So you have only one computer, so any cache application that store the cache on the database on the same computer can do the work.

The key point here is to have a database to keep the cache, because pools can not direact talk to each other and share resources, and the only way to have share data (like cache) is using common database, or common files, or common memory file-map.

The most safer, faster and ready to go is the database.

The Windows Server App Fabric can hold that, can also hold many other computers.

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC358167.gif))</sub>

Alternative, for web garden and a single computer, if you can handle a database on your project you can easy create your own cache, with a single table, and using mutex for synchronize the data